# d3 transition for expanding div

Tags: javascript, css, svg, d3.js

I want to create a transition within my d3 object where I hover on a svg rectangle and beyond the svg object a div expands with the datavalues in it:

I have the following variables for my divs:

```
var answer = d3.select("body").select("div.answer");
var datablock = answer.select("p.data");
```

In order to extend `answer` on hover of my svg object:

```
.on("mouseover"), function(d) {
      answer.transition()
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("height",200)
            .style("border", "1px solid black");
      datablock.text(d.name+" = "+d.age);  
    }
```

but it is not working, am I doing something wrong when addressing the height of the div?
There are some other transitions which are all working exept this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `<div>` element does not have a height attribute it has a height CSS style that must have units to be valid unless the height is 0.